# j2me playing video

Tags: java, video, java-me

The player doesn't play videos stored in project (File in res and src )

```
public class videoplayer extends MIDlet {
       Display display;
       Player player;

       public videoplayer() {
          try{
                display = Display.getDisplay(this);
                InputStream is =getClass().getResourceAsStream("/a1.mpg");
                player = Manager.createPlayer(is,"video/mpeg");

          }catch(Exception e)
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }

       protected void startApp() {        
           try {
                 VideoControl vc;
                 player.realize();
                 vc = (VideoControl)player.getControl("VideoControl");
                 if(vc != null) {
                    Item video = (Item)vc.initDisplayMode(vc.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, null);
                    Form v = new Form("Playing Video...");
                    v.append(video);
                    display.setCurrent(v);
                 }
                 player.prefetch();
                 player.start();
              }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

       }
```

but it shows following exceptions in run time. i tried this code by storing file in res and with src but same exceptions.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 - javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer(), bci=8
 - videoplayer.videoplayer.<init>(), bci=25
 - java.lang.Class.newInstance(), bci=0
 - com.sun.midp.main.CldcMIDletLoader.newInstance(), bci=46
 - com.sun.midp.midlet.MIDletStateHandler.createMIDlet(), bci=66
 - com.sun.midp.midlet.MIDletStateHandler.createAndRegisterMIDlet(), bci=17
 - com.sun.midp.midlet.MIDletStateHandler.startSuite(), bci=27
 - com.sun.midp.main.AbstractMIDletSuiteLoader.startSuite(), bci=52
 - com.sun.midp.main.CldcMIDletSuiteLoader.startSuite(), bci=8
 - com.sun.midp.main.AbstractMIDletSuiteLoader.runMIDletSuite(), bci=161
 - com.sun.midp.main.AppIsolateMIDletSuiteLoader.main(), bci=26
java.lang.NullPointerException:   0
 - videoplayer.videoplayer.startApp(), bci=4
 - javax.microedition.midlet.MIDletTunnelImpl.callStartApp(), bci=1
 - com.sun.midp.midlet.MIDletPeer.startApp(), bci=7
 - com.sun.midp.midlet.MIDletStateHandler.startSuite(), bci=269
 - com.sun.midp.main.AbstractMIDletSuiteLoader.startSuite(), bci=52
 - com.sun.midp.main.CldcMIDletSuiteLoader.startSuite(), bci=8
 - com.sun.midp.main.AbstractMIDletSuiteLoader.runMIDletSuite(), bci=161
 - com.sun.midp.main.AppIsolateMIDletSuiteLoader.main(), bci=26
```

**EDIT:** directory structure

[image]

Comment: and where have you placed the file ?

Comment: @Jigar Joshi Tried with placing it in "res" folder and move it to "src" folder but the result is same

Comment: can you add your dir structure & location of file currently placed in the build not in the source.

Comment: @Jigar check my edit to find directory structure

Comment: and where the file is placed?

Comment: @Jigar now see the structure . I have tried with placing the file in res but no success then tried with placing it in src>videoplayer but no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the file into `res` and put `res` under `src`

so it should be

`src` \ `res`

and in code

```
InputStream is =getClass().getResourceAsStream("res/a1.mpg")
```

**Update** on your second issue

go to

> /runtimes/cldc-hi/bin/jwc_properties.ini

find the property `system.jam_space` raise its value

Comment: ya exception cleared but it shows " *** Error ***
A problem occured during deploying application from http://127.0.0.1:5101/videoplayer1.jad
Reason:
There is insufficient storage to install this suite"

Comment: seems you double copied the file. or file size is too large for the emulator/phone

Comment: no only single copy there and already delete the res folder outside src. And the file size is less than 1 Mb (612 kb)

Comment: thanks jigar. it reverts the same exception when i change it from 1000000 to  10000000 (adding a zero)

Answer (score 2):

try with the prefix `file://` before the file path.

Comment: Did you mean file://a1.mpg . If so it also results the same exception

Comment: it should be `file:///a1.mpg`, `file://` is the "protocol" and `/a1.mpg` is the path.

Comment: Well, @Paniyar, I'm sorry to hear that, the only other option I suggest is to check the encoding format, try some other video. Good luck!