# Video Recording in j2me

Tags: java-me

I am doing task in j2me which record the video and save in memory card and displaying it in the canvas. The problem is I want to take snap shoot for displaying the video properly, to be clear for a thumbnail, I used the code

```
public Image getScreenShot() {
 screenshot = Image.createImage(getWidth(), 
                     getHeight());
  Graphics g = screenshot.getGraphics();
  paint(g);
  return screenshot;
}
```

It gives a null pointer exception. Now my problem is, Is it possible to get a thumbnail for a video in j2me, Anybody suggest some other ways for it??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `VideoControl` class from `javax.microedition.media.control.VideoControl`you can save of of the frames while processing it (before you display it on the screen) with:

```
byte[] raw = videoControl.getSnapshot(null);
Image image = Image.createImage(raw, 0, raw.length);
```

Before displaying the image on the form with

```
form.append(image);
display.setCurrent(form);
```

Just save it to the storage.

Full source code for running a video (captured tho) can be found [here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_display_the_camera_&_take_snapshots_in_Java_ME) and using VideoControl to play recorded videos [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022408/j2me-playing-video)